ASP.NET Core exception : cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' after creating a 1-to-1 relationship with identityuser
I'm just converting now over to ASP.NET Core from using ASP.NET MVC a lot. I have a VS 2022 project targeting .NET 8.0.
I wanted to create a 1-to-1 table relationship with the IdentityUser to store extra information such as a person or a profile).
Everything compiles, however when I try to register, I get the following exception:

Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' because this type is not included in the model for the context

I know why I am getting it, its because my DbContext now has DbSet<CustomUser>.
What is the best way of achieving this 1-to-1 relationship between IdentityUser and person and keep as much of the standard identity code intact as possible?
Here is my model:
public class CustomUser : IdentityUser
{
    public Person? Person { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string Surname { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public long DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public long LocationId { get; set; }

    public CustomUser AppUser { get; set; }
}

Here is my DbContext:
public class ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) 
    : IdentityDbContext<CustomUser>(options)
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<CustomUser>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Person)
            .WithOne(c => c.AppUser)
            .HasForeignKey<Person>(x => x.PersonId);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}

The code fails at the following line within the login post processing.
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password); 

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Regarding to this error:

Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' because this type is not included in the model for the context

I can reproduce if I still use
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddUserManager<UserManager<IdentityUser>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

And inject UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager in the controller.
But you will need to change all the IdentityUser to CustomUser. Just search all over the project and replace them will solve this error.
According to your needs to extend properties for IdentityUser, you could easily extend them within the CustomUser class:
    public class CustomUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string Surname { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public long DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public long LocationId { get; set; }
    }

If you still want 1-to-1 relationship, you could specify the foreignkeys for them by attribute.
    public class CustomUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [ForeignKey("Person")]
        public string? FK_PersonId { get; set; }
        public Person? Person { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public string PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string Surname { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public long DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public long LocationId { get; set; }

        public CustomUser AppUser { get; set; }
    }

Then you just need following in DbContext.
            builder.Entity<CustomUser>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Person)
                .WithOne(c => c.AppUser);

